# Windows 10 PC is constantly freezing, stuttering and looping

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, graphics-card, motherboard, hardware-failure

My current PC build has been experiencing crashes. This all started happening after a bad lightning storm near my home. It fried the Ethernet port on my Modem, which I returned, and perhaps my Motherboard, but I am not sure. The reason I think that is because there used to be an LED light when my Ethernet cord was plugged in, I was able to get a new modem and things were ‘working’ but now my PC is constantly stuttering, freezing, getting stuck on startup repair(looping), artifacting on startup, pretty much every weird occurrence is happening.

** NOTE: Everything is plugged into a surge protector **

Also – I have installed my video drivers several times, when I restart my computer if it has not been on for a while, I will be back to only 1 monitor at 800 x 600, instead of 3 monitors @ 1920 x 1080.

Any idea what the culprit is? I am leaning towards the GPU being faulty. I have run MEMtest, which passed everything, the computer is very operable in BIOS/Advanced Startup, but it refuses to boot normally to Windows, and when it does it is the choppiest worst user experience I have ever had.
Any insight would be appreciated, like I said, I think it’s the GPU but that is a huge expense to replace right now.

My build is:

**Windows 10

ASUS P8Z77-V LX Motherboard

i5-3570k 3.4 GHz CPU

EVGA nVidia GeForce GTX 780

16 GB Corsair Vengeance DDR3 @ 1600 MHz

ThermalTake SmartPower 750w PSU

Boot Drive – 120gb Samsung 840 EVO

Game Drive – 256gb Samsung 850 Pro

Data Drive – 750gb Western Digital Blue 7200 RPM**

Comment: It could even be the HDD/SSDs. Or the mobo... or anything to be honest. It's hard to say.

Comment: Yeah... that's where I'm at. When I get home later I'm gonna boot with 1 stick of RAM and see if it still throws errors, otherwise I may try to migrate all my data and see if I can make everything work with only 1 SSD & HDD. If not... then back to the drawing board.

Comment: I think more that the power supply unit is broken. GPU uses in some setting more power, and it trigger the reboots.

Comment: It isn't just auto-rebooting. It is freezing, which forces a reboot. Could be my SSD... but that wouldn't explain the artifacting I get sometimes when booting into Windows.

Comment: I'd recommend you try tracking your system's performance while you have all the secondary storage drives unplugged from the system, @t a b! Make sure you leave only the booting SSD and see how the system will behave then. If the issue is still present, you should definitely consider performing full diagnostics and troubleshooting all the hardware components one by one. Keep us posted & good luck!

Comment: I have been getting the nvlddmkm.sys blue screen error as well.

Thanks @SuperSoph_WD

Comment: This seems odd. You mentioned that you have reinstalled the GPU drivers several times, right? Maybe you should re-install them again and make sure you do that through the Nvidia's official website. Have you tried taking the RAM sticks out one by one to see if that will help? Another thing that could help is running Windows Updates and see if the BSOD will still continue afterwards. [Testing the PSU](http://www.wikihow.com/Check-a-Power-Supply) is not a bad idea either. Hope this helps.

Comment: It was my GPU. Ended up swapping out the 780 for a 1070, downgraded to 8.1, verified things were working as intended and then upgraded to W10. Everything seems stable at the moment. It's a shame my $600 gpu didn't last more than 3 years.. Oh well, shiny new computer parts are always cool! Thanks for the help.